# Migrating forum from phpBB 3.0.9 to nodeBB 1.14.2, without migrating accounts

Tags: database-migration, phpbb3, nodebb

How do I migrate a forum from `phpBB 3.0.9` to `nodeBB 1.14.2`?

I've found some plugins but I'm pretty sure the version differences will cause major headaches :

- [importer wrong phpBB and nodeBB verions](https://github.com/akhoury/nodebb-plugin-import)
- [migration exporter ?](https://github.com/elelel/nodebb-plugin-import-phpbb)
- [exporter closest version match but not quite : pbpBB 3.1](https://github.com/belst/nodebb-plugin-import-phpbb)
- [post migration, convert to markdown](https://github.com/elelel/phpbb3bbcode2markdown4nodebb)

Also I'm not quite sure of the procedure?

Is it remote connect to the `phpBB` server stop the forum and install the exporter plugin then start  the forum and pick up the entire forum as one database file, then stop new `nodeBB` forum install plugin then start the new forum and import the file?

it's unclear from what's given.

I also have some perhaps unusual requirements :

I'm not interested in migrating accounts, in fact I specifically do not want to migrate accounts. the migration exists only as comfort for those who want to be able to look up the old archived threads (btw I will mark them all as read-only after migration) but effectively we are starting from scratch with new accounts.

So I'm not interested in migrating the accounts and I'm wondering if that's an issue? do posts necessarily need to be created with an account or is creating posts made by an unattributed user name possible? (if `nodeBB` attributes posts from the old forum archive to a new forum joinee that's perfectly fine by me, not so if `nodeBB` refuses that a new joinee use that name under pretext that it's already under use. New users and content must take priority)

will `nodeBB` allow this or will it require a account named "archivebot" for example to be "responsible", the "author" of all these posts. I'd prefer if I could at least preserve the author names but if I can't that's an ok sacrifice.

Also will nodeBB allow the original dates for the posts? or will all of them be of the date of the migration?

**TLDR:** I don't know how to migrate from `phpBB 3.0.9` to `nodeBB 1.14.2` specifically there doesn't seem to be an upgrade path for those specific version numbers.